# Flutter Web-Proper way to use both of onGenerateRoute and routes as properties of MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, flutter-web

I have a browser link of reset password that sent by email`(http://trialxx.id/#/auth?email=trial@email.com )`, so whenever user click that link I would like to navigate them to ResetPasswordScreen. So far I have been declaring the route inside `onGenerateRoute`, here is the code

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final settingsUri = Uri.parse(settings.name);
    final postID = settingsUri.queryParameters['email'];
    const start = "#/";
    const end = "?";
    final startIndex = settings.name.indexOf(start);
    final endIndex = settings.name.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);
    if (settings.name.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex) ==
            "auth" &&
        postID != null &&
        postID != "") {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => RisetPasswordScreen(email: settings.name),
          settings: RouteSettings(
              name: '/${settings.name.substring(startIndex + start.length)}'));
    }
    else {
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstScreen());
    }
  }
```

but, I didn't able to define it inside `routes` property, here is the way I define the route

```
MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      title: 'e-Recruitment',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
      if (Uri.base.queryParameters['email'] != null &&
            Uri.base.queryParameters['email'] != "")
          if (Uri.base.toString().substring(
                  Uri.base.toString().indexOf("#/") + 2,
                  Uri.base
                      .toString()
                      .indexOf("?", Uri.base.toString().indexOf("#/") + 2)) ==
              "auth")
            '/auth': (context) => RisetPasswordScreen()
          else
            '/home': (context) => FirstScreen(),
      '/': (context) => AnotherPage(),
      '/second': (context) => SecondPage(),
      })
```

so am I doing wrong or is there a proper way to define the routes of `/auth?email=trial@email.com` inside routes property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep routes simple. You want to define one route name per screen without any wildcards (as you try in your example).

In your material define only routes without parameters:

```
Widget test(){
    return MaterialApp(
       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
       title: 'e-Recruitment',
       initialRoute: '/',
       routes: {
       '/auth': (context) => RisetPasswordScreen(),
       '/home': (context) => FirstScreen(),
       '/': (context) => AnotherPage(),
       '/second': (context) => SecondPage(),
    });
}
```

Then in your `generateRoute()` function parse uri just like you did, but without complicating things too much - parameter *name* in **RouteSettings** contains only path after **/#**. So if your link is `http://trialxx.id/#/auth?email=trial@email.com`, then `settings.name` will be `/auth?email=trial@email.com`

```
 Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    var uri = Uri.parse(settings.name);
    switch (uri.path) {
      case home:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage());
        break;
      case auth:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                ResetPasswordPage(email: uri.queryParameters["email"]));
        break;
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ErrorPage());
    }
  }
```

Pass email as variable to the page and handle its logic there

Comment: that's really great, I have tried your answer and it works very good like what I want... thank you so much for your help